# Inserting blank rows in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

[Final One:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMUZ9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvIhl.png)I want to insert blank row with a specific column range above a particular row.
For example:
There were 2 sets of data in a single sheet ,ie, 1st set col A to Col E and 2nd set Col F to Col J. I need to compare Column Ai with Column Fi  (where i indicates the position of row) and if both values are same then the comparison can be proceeded like Bi with Gi, Ci with Hi and so and so and if not, I need to shift that set of 2nd data Fi to Ji to next row..ie. if the whole set is in 6th position I need to shift them down to 7th position and make the 6th position of Fi to Ji blank....

```
 Sub Dcompare()
 Dim endRow As Long
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

 endRow = Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 2 To endRow
 If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("F" & i).Value Then
    Sheet1.Range("K" & i).Value = "Yes"

 Else
 ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value = ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" &    i).Value
 ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Value = ""


 End If 

 Next i

For j = 2 To endRow
If Sheet1.Range("K" & j).Value = "Yes" Then
If Sheet1.Range("B" & j).Value = Sheet1.Range("G" & j).Value Then
   Sheet1.Range("L" & j).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("L" & j).Value = "No"
End If
If Sheet1.Range("C" & j).Value = Sheet1.Range("H" & j).Value Then
   Sheet1.Range("M" & j).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("M" & j).Value = "No"
End If
If Sheet1.Range("D" & j).Value = Sheet1.Range("I" & j).Value Then
    Sheet1.Range("N" & j).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("N" & j).Value = "No"
End If
If Sheet1.Range("E" & j).Value = Sheet1.Range("J" & j).Value Then
     Sheet1.Range("O" & j).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("O" & j).Value = "No"
End If
End If
Next j
End Sub


------>Final Code Inserted---------

Sub Dcompare()
Dim endRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dShift As Boolean
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
endRow = ws.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To endRow + 1

If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value Then
dShift = False
ws.Range("K" & i).Value = "Yes"
Else
If Not dShift Then
ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown,               CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ws.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":E" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown,   CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
     endRow = endRow + 1
     dShift = True
     Else
     dShift = False
     End If
     End If


 j = i
 If ws.Range("K" & j).Value = "Yes" Then
 If ws.Range("B" & j).Value = ws.Range("G" & j).Value Then
 ws.Range("L" & j).Value = "Yes"
 Else
     ws.Range("L" & j).Value = "No"
 End If
 If ws.Range("C" & j).Value = ws.Range("H" & j).Value Then
    ws.Range("M" & j).Value = "Yes"
 Else
     ws.Range("M" & j).Value = "No"
 End If
 If ws.Range("D" & j).Value = ws.Range("I" & j).Value Then
     ws.Range("N" & j).Value = "Yes"
 Else
     ws.Range("N" & j).Value = "No"
 End If
 If ws.Range("E" & j).Value = ws.Range("J" & j).Value Then
      ws.Range("O" & j).Value = "Yes"
 Else
     ws.Range("O" & j).Value = "No"
 End If
 Else
 End If

 Next i
 MsgBox "The value of endRow is : " & endRow, vbInformation

 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the new problem you were talking about in the comment to my answer?

Comment: @Vegard 
more than one blank row is inserted nw..

Comment: @Vegard:
Please refer the image of the current output attached with the question..there u can see that more than one blank row is inserted...I need only single blank row ...

Comment: So when a line is evaluated and found to not match, you want it moved down 1 row and nothing more, regardless of other circumstances?

Comment: yes..that 2nd set of row(F->J)...and after  moving down the comparison should continue till it find the matching value.....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In the image you describe, there is no matching value for the row that has been shifted down twice instead of once. So you first said that a row should never be shifted more than one time, but now you are saying it needs to be shifted as many times as is necessary to find a match. Which is it?

Comment: @Vegard
row should never be shifted more than once..

Comment: Are you sure you don't want just the value that doesn't match to move? Like with the range in your picture that has been moved down 2 rows - do you want to move that entire range (F to J) exactly 1 row down, or do you want to move only "2258" and leave the rest up there? And if a row ends up being moved, do you want the "Yes"/"No" boxes to be filled out in one or both of the helper columns?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if there is already some value in the row below something you want to move? Do you want to move the entire set of data downwards, or do you intend to overwrite whatever is present in that particular range?

Comment: I need to move the entire range(F to J) exactly 1 row down...dont want to overwrite....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanations, this is what I interpret your challenge as:

- Evaluate `Ai` with `Fi` --> `Ei` with `Ji` from left to right, and indicate in helper-columns whether the evaluation succeeded or not
- If the first evaluation is `Not Equal`, offset the range `Fi:Ji` downwards exactly one row
- If a range has been shifted down, the loop should evaluate this line but never shift it again regardless of outcome of the evaluation

This code satisfies those conditions (change `i` and other row variables to your needs):

```
Sub Dcompare()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dShift As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    endRow = ws.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set initial value of helper columns to no - saves miniscule time and complexity in the loop
    ws.Range("L" & 1 & ":O" & endRow).Value = "No"

    For i = 1 To endRow
        If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value Then
            dShift = False
            ws.Range("L" & i).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            If Not dShift Then
                ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                ' Remember that we just shifted a row
                dShift = True
            Else
                ' Reset shift counter
                dShift = False
            End If
        End If

        For j = 2 To 4
            If dShift Then Exit For
            If ws.Cells(i, j).Value = ws.Cells(i, j + 5).Value Then ws.Cells(i, j + 11).Value = "Yes"
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, it seems strange to me that you would want this functionality? Please confirm that it is correct. The behavior it yields in the worksheet is very strange.

Let me show with images. Orange background means the code will show the cell as a match. Green background means the code will show that the cell doesn't match.

Before the code it looks like this:

[image]

After the code it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are using and describe more closely what the problem is, and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thankyou so much...now I can shift down the row , but seems to be some problem with the loop...I am sharing my code with this...can u plz hav a look on this....
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
endRow = Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To endRow
If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("F" & i).Value Then
Sheet1.Range("K" & i).Value = "Yes"
Else
ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value = ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Value
ws.Range("F" & i & ":J" & i).Value = ""
End If, Next i
For j = 2 To endRow 
rest of the comparison.if the above condition is true/yes

Comment: Put this code into your question, so you can format it proper. It's very hard to read this code in a comment. You should also describe the problem you are having more closely.

Comment: Well, the images are made using the code that is currently in the answer, so if that truly is the functionality you wanted, it should be pretty much ready for use as soon as you re-define `i` and change the `1` in the first commented line of code.

Comment: Yes,above images shows the expected behaviour.
1. Evaluate Ai with Fi --> Ei with Ji from left to right, and indicate in helper-columns whether the evaluation succeeded or not: correct assumption

2. If any of the evaluations are Not Equal, offset the range Fi:Ji downwards exactly one row: not any of the evaluations, only Ai and Fi. In the case of other cells just output as False in helper columns.Other cells are compared only when Ai=Fi

3. If a range has been shifted down, the loop should evaluate this line but never shift it again regardless of outcome of the evaluation: crct assmption

Comment: Regarding #2, I didn't update the description of the problem, but the code does what you've stated is correct behavior.

Comment: Thankyou so much Vegard: its working as expected..however I hv to add new behavior based on new  requirements...But this helped me a lot...

Comment: You're welcome. If the question was solved, please indicate this to other reads by marking the answer as a solution by clicking the checkmark next to the voting buttons. :)

Comment: Made a small adjustment to the code to account for a minor contingency.

Comment: Facing a small problem with helper columns: outputs true value for mismatch also....

Comment: Can you give example data? Include the entire row + the row above it.

Comment: I don't see any example data, can you please add it?

Comment: exaple data image saved as 'Final One'.

Comment: All outputs that are true should be true, in that example data, if I understood your problem correctly. Can you clarify which values are getting "yes", but should be getting "no"?

Comment: I hv one more doubt. How can we specify the number of blank rows to insert. for eg: if my current data is in 3rd row and I need to shift down the data to 7th row by inserting blank...(making 3rd row to 6th row blank)

Comment: here we can take Ai and Fi as primary key.If Ai and Fi match, then only next level of comparison takes place. If Ai and Fi hav same value, will output True(yes) and compares the helper columns Bi-Gi, Ci-Hi, Di-Ji respectively. If Bi and Ci hv same value then it will output Yes else No. Same as in the case of other columns too...If Ai and Fi doesnt match then blank rows are inserted..

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to do, but you aren't telling me what is going wrong.

Comment: actually wat the reason is the requirement is changing every tym... nw the new requirement is if Ai != Fi, then compare Fi with  Ai   by incrementing the i-th value of  column A . ie; (Ai+1,Ai+2...)until Fi meets the same value. And when Fi meets the same value in Ai+x shift down the F-J set to xth position..
dat was my above question (for eg: if my current data is in 3rd row and I need to shift down the data to 7th row by inserting blank...(making 3rd row to 6th row blank) –)